# $f = 0 $ almost everywhere implies $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

my try: Suppose $\phi $ is imple function such that $ 0 \leq \phi \leq f$, then since $ f = 0 $ almost everywhere, then $\phi = 0 $ almost everywhere.  Let $A = \{ x : \phi(x) = 0\}$. Therefore, $A^c = \{x : \phi(x) > 0 \}$ is a null set. Hence

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi = \int_A \phi + \int_{A^c} \phi = 0 + 0  = 0  $$

Since $\mathbb{R} = A \cup A^c $. therefore $\int_\mathbb{R} f = 0$

is this a correct solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally let
$$f_+ := \max(f,0); f_- := \max(-f,0)$$
Then
$$f = f_+ + f_-$$
Since $f_+, f_- \ge 0$,
$$f = 0 \Rightarrow f_+ = f_- = 0$$
Since this holds a.e., we have
$$f_+, f_- = 0 \quad\text{a.e.}$$
Proceed with your argument using a series of step functions for both, $f_+$ and $f_-$ to get
$$\int_{\mathbb R} f = \int_{\mathbb R} f_+ - \int_{\mathbb R} f_- = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb R} f_+^{(n)} - \int_{\mathbb R} f_-^{(n)} = 0$$
Where you use $f_+^{(n)} \nearrow f_+, f_-^{(n)} \nearrow f_-$.

Comment: A (positive) step function can't be smaller than a function which vanishes on a set of full measure.

Comment: It sure can be. Maybe you know "step function" as "elementary function" though,
$$f = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \chi_{A_i}$$
where $\chi_X$ is a characterisic function and $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint sets.

Answer (score 2):

For general $f$ decompose $f=f_+ -f_-$ and argue separately for the nonnegative functions $f_\pm$.  If $f$ vanishes almost everywhere then so do $f_\pm$.

Comment: The OP already seems to have argued for the $f_{+}$ case.. but the $A^c$ being null seems a very fishy argument to base the rest of the proof on.

Comment: Why is it fishy?

Comment: Hmm, my bad. I thought that they meant null as in devoid of elements. It's almost obvious that $A^c$ is negligible, but might be good to prove it (should take two lines at most :) ).